# Cartodb API Read Only

Tags: carto, sql, api

Is it possible to generate an API-key in Cartodb with read-only permission?

Seems like the default API-key has full controll

Answer (score 1):

At this moment CartoDB only offers a single API key per user which as you say, is full control.

Comment: Wondering how playing with functions + security definers would allow you to set up specific functions to retrieve specific data in an unauthorized way :-)